# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'url' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: magento2, error

This is my code

```
<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
$json=$block->getGalleryImagesJson();
$array = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($array as $item)
{
    $imgurl = $item['full'];
    echo '<img alt="main product photo" class="gallery-placeholder__image" ".$imgurl['url']. "/>';
   <br>
}
?> 
</div>
```

and I am getting error  on this line

```
echo '<img alt="main product photo" class="gallery-placeholder__image" ".$imgurl['url']. "/>';
```

as

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'url' (T_STRING), expecting ','
>   or ';' in
>   C:\wamp64\www\ekelund1692\app\design\frontend\Pronko\ekelund\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\gallery.phtml
>   on line 8

Answer (score 0):

replace below code hope it's work for you

```
<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    $json=$block->getGalleryImagesJson();
    $array = json_decode($json,true); ?>
    <?php foreach($array as $item): ?>
        <?php 
        $imgurl = $item['full'];
        echo '<img alt="main product photo" class="gallery-placeholder__image" src="'.$imgurl['url'].'">'; 
        ?>
        <br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: By adding this code div class disappears

Answer (score 0):

You used image tag without src attribute.

Change your line to :

```
<?php echo "<img alt='main product photo' class='gallery-placeholder_image' src='".$imgurl['url']."' />"; ?>
```

And also remove `<br>` tag after error line, as direct `<br>` tag inside PHP is not allowed. either remove or change it to :

```
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: no still that error

Comment: Can you edit answer with last code after changes and error as well ?

Comment: Edited answer, please try that as well and see.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$imgurl' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it works.

```
  <div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
    $json=$block->getGalleryImagesJson();
    $array = json_decode($json,true);
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        $imgurl = $item['full'];
        echo '<img alt="main product photo" class="gallery-placeholder__image" src="'.$imgurl['url'].'"/>';
       echo "<br/>";
    }
    ?> 
    </div>
```